# Finding the extrema on sphere edges

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the extrema on sphere $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ for the function $x^3 + y^3 -3xy$, i have tried to use the rail $P(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$ but wasn't capable to find it's differential roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Your substitution works.  Abbreviate $c=\cos(t)$, $s=\sin(t)$.  Plug that in and take the derivative to arrive in
$$3(s-c)(sc+s+c)=0.$$
Now the second factor is equal to
$$(s+1)(c+1)-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the equation of the sphere to eliminate one variable:
$$y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ so you will get $$f(x,\pm\sqrt{1-x^2})=x^3+\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}^3-3x(\pm\sqrt{1-x^2})$$